# How to display dictionary values using mvc view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a dictionary in my mvc controller and storing values,so i want to display these values using view.

My codes

```
 public List<Dictionary<string, string>> getalllocation()
     {
        var locs = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        try
         {
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            string connString = cnst.cnstrin();
            string query = "SELECT * FROM `Mytable`.`location`";
            MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            ma.Fill(dt1);

            foreach (DataRow drow in dt1.Rows)
             {
               Dictionary<string, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
               dictionary.Add("id", drow["LocationId"].ToString());
               dictionary.Add("name", drow["LocationName"].ToString());
               locs.Add(dictionary);
             }
           }
        catch (MySqlException e)
         {
           throw new Exception(e.Message);
         }
        return locs;
      }
```

I my view

```
@{
  List<Dictionary<string,string>>locations=((HomeController)this.ViewContext.Controller).getalllocation();
  }
 <select name="select_item" id="select-sort" class="select__sort" tabindex="0">

                @for (int i=0;i<locations.Count;i++)
                {
                    if((i==0)&&(ViewBag.location==null))
                    { }
                 }
         <option value="1" selected='selected'>@locations</option>//I need to display here
                 </select>
```

Right now i unable to display values,but data is on locations.Any idea?

Comment: Awful approach. Create a model with properties `string ID` and `string Name` and return `List<yourModel>`. Then in the view use `DropDownListFor()` to generate your select.

Comment: @StephenMuecke:can you please show me any example?

Comment: I strongly recommend you go to the MVC site and work through the tutorials to understand the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the following helper:

```
@helper GenerateSelect(List<Dictionary<string, string>> dict)
{
    foreach (var item in dict)
    {
        <option value="@item["id"]">@item["name"]</option>
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
<select name="select_item" id="select-sort" class="select__sort" tabindex="0">
    @GenerateSelect(locations)    
</select>
```

However, as already mentionted by other people, **it is a really bad approach to use dictionaries with pre-defined keys**.

You can create a new class:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

generate a `List<Location>`:

```
public List<Location> GetAllocation()
{
    try
    {
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        string connString = cnst.cnstrin();
        string query = "SELECT * FROM `Mytable`.`location`";
        MySqlDataAdapter ma = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, connString);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        ma.Fill(dt1);

        return dt1.AsEnumerable().Select(row => new Location {
            Id = row["LocationId"],
            Name = row["LocationName"]
        });
    }
    catch (MySqlException e)
    {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

pass it to your View as Model, and generate a `select`:

```
@model List<Location>

<select name="select_item" id="select-sort" class="select__sort" tabindex="0">
    @foreach (var loc in Model)
    {
        <option value="@loc.Id">@loc.Name</option>
    }
</select>
```

Comment: Instead of using List<Dictionary<string, string>>, you can suggest him to use List<Tuple<string, string>>. What is the use of Dictionary if it is just going to contain one item?